# Deconstruct and rename values to string keys

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Any way I can do something like this? I need specific names for values...

```
const {
  firstNm: 'my-funny-first-name',
  lastNm: 'bar-foo_Bar'
} = response;
```

Comment: `my-funny-first-name` is not a valid variable name

Comment: Please show us what `response` looks like and what result (which variables declared with what values) you expect. I really can't tell from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable names can't contain hyphens (`-`), so you can't.

But, you can still rename the destructured properties, as long as their names are valid identifiers:

```js
const {
  firstNm: my_funny_first_name,
  lastNm: bar_foo_Bar
} = response;
```

Note that you can't quote those names, but you don't have to at all:

- Valid identifier names can be written without quotes, and
- Invalid identifier names are unallowed at that place.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, however you need to use valid variable names and you can omit the quotes. In other words:

```
const { firstNm: myFunnyFirstName, lastNm: barFooBar } = response
```

^ This will create new variables `myFunnyFirstName` and `barFooBar` to represent `response.firstNm` and `response.lastNm`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `my-funny-first-name` to `myFunnyFirstName`, because you cannot have dashes in a variable name.

```js
var response = {
  "firstNm" : "Billy-Bob",
  "lastNm"  : "Foo Bar"
};

const {
  firstNm: myFunnyFirstName,
  lastNm: barFooBar
} = response;

console.log(`myFunnyFirstName = ${myFunnyFirstName}\nbarFooBar = ${barFooBar}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```